# How can I match a curve to a path?

Tags: bezier-curves, path

I am attempting to make a car follow a path. I also have a road following a curve. I was thinking that i should have the path match the shape of the curve then offset the car slightly to drive on the surface but am struggling to do so. Is there a way to achieve that? Is there a better way I should be trying to achieve this?

Comment: Hello why don't you use the same curve, or duplicate it for your car?

Comment: I am not sure that will work because i need the car to be lined up directly with the road the the first curve is following. I think i need the car to follow a separate path. Also, when i try to parent>follow path on the bezier curve, it animated incorrectly.

Comment: You can duplicate the curve and move the duplicated, or parent the car to an empty and make the mepty follow the curve, etc. As for the incorrect animation, hard to tell without the file